# why is ipod 2g not compatible with my app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, app-store, itunes, compatibility

I build my app as a universal app. The deployment target is 3.0 and the required device capabilities are accelerometer and opengles-1.
It works on iPhone 3g and upwards, iPod 3/4 and iPad 1/2. But if I want to download it on the Appstore it says "Not compatible". Has anyone an idea?
I use cocos2d 9.9.5 as engine.

Comment: Have you compiled it as ARMv7 only binary?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The valid architectures are ARMv7 ARMv6 and i368

Comment: Wouldn't have run on iPhone 3G if it was armv7 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like the jailbreak is responsible for the problem. It runs on non jailbreaked iPod Touch 2g. Miracle dissolved.